# Custom animations that don't relate to layers. (onTick closure)

Tags: swift

I want to write a function that animates text inside the label. So, obviously i don't get to use any CABaseAnimations that modify the layer property. What i want to a have is a closure function that gets called all the time when the value is changed.

So, for instance, hypothetically:

```
 SomeAnimationSolution.animate(
   from: 0.1, to : 2.0, interval : 1, .EaseInOut, onTick : { (currentValue) in
    // Here i do whatever i need to to with currentValue
 })
```

I was not able to find anything related. I have even starting writing my own NSTimer implementation. I guess that's because of despair. (or not?)

Can you guys advise?